# Как написать собственное исключение в отдельном классе и вызывать его при надобности?

Tags: c#

Как написать собственное исключение в отдельном классе и вызывать его при надобности? Заранее спасибо!

Можете ли описать что и куда вписывать? Я пока еще новичок и не особо понимаю.
Вот само исключение, оно проверяет является ли вектор нулевым (v1 и v2 это векторы, а len1 и len2 их длины):

```
//exeption
    try
    {
        len1 = v1.Length();
        len2 = v2.Length();

        if (len1 == 0 || len2 == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Вектор не может быть нулевым");

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nОшибка: " + e.Message);
        test = 10;
    }
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы создать свое исключение, нужно создать класс и отнаследовать его от одного из типов исключений, в зависимости от ваших потребностей. Чаще всего, собственные исключения просто наследуют от класса `Exception`.

Далее, чтобы ваше исключение соответствовало общепринятым стандартам, вам нужно иметь как минимум три конструктора: по умолчанию (без параметров), конструктор с сообщением, конструктор с сообщением и оригинальным исключением. Последний теоретически может быть опущен, но являетсмя обязательным, если вы "оборачиваете" какие-то системное исключением своим исключением.

(Для продвинутых: если исключение будет передаваться через границы, то обязательно нужно включить конструктор для сериализации. Подробнее в правиле FxCop'а.)

Кроме того, вы вольны включать в исключение любую дополнительную информацию, которая может помочь коду, обрабатывающему ваше исключение, принять нужное решение.

Итого:

```
[Serializable] // опционально
public class GoodException : Exception
{
    public GoodException()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public GoodException(string message) : base(message) 
    {
        // ...
    }

    public GoodException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base (message, innerException)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // опционально
    protected GoodException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
      : base(info, context)
    {
        // логика сериализации
    }

    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну и хотелось бы дополнить предыдущий ответ перегрузкой с конструктором, принимающим текст самой ошибки:

```
internal class MyException : Exception
{
    public MyException(string message): base(message)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
}

public class MyClass
{
  public void Execute()
  {
    throw new MyException();
  }
}
```